# Cleanup badge awarded when answer was deleted and reposted?

Tags: feature-request, badges, revisions-list, clean-up, rollbacks

I accidentally posted some code during an edit in an answer that I did not want to be public. Couldn't just rollback the edit to really get rid of it. Deleted the answer and reposted modified without private info. Awarded a cleanup badge.

Comment: What exactly is the feature request?

Comment: Think it should be retagged "bug" so it can just be marked "status-bydesign"?

Comment: Deletes don't really go away, there's just a restricted set of people who can see them.  You might want to contact a moderator or the SO team about getting the private information really deleted if you're concerned about security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you can't see it, that deleted answer is still there in the system.  Anyone with > 10k of reputation would be able to see your answer and your code, so as tvanfosson says, you should probably contact a mod to delete it (flag your answer or something with a little note for them).

Comment: can't flag the deleted answer

Comment: maybe flag your other one but ask the mod to delete your first answer (you have a bit of room in the message box to write this)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about  it.

You did a rollback; you earned a badge. There's no productive way the system can determine that your rollback turned out *not* to be needed. What if you deleted the message days (or years) later?

Once awarded, badges are *rarely* removed. It's okay.

Comment: *Never removed